# No SQLite write access for django-apache-wsgi app

Tags: django, sqlite

The debug screen says that django does not have write access to the db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably the userid under which your app is running doesn't have write permissions on the file in which you've saved your DB, or there are permission issues with some directory on the path.  So what does ls -l or -ld (or Windows equivalent) say about all relevant permissions, and what userid is the webapp running under?

Comment: this was it, thanks. i had to give write permission on the db and the directory.